# Why am I getting this error when I run my Powershell script to enable bitlocker

Tags: windows, powershell, bitlocker

I have a script that is supposed to enable Bitlocker on a windows device.
This is the script I have so far.

```
# Define the length of the random string
$length = 48

# Define the character set
$characters = '1234567890'

# Create a random string
$randomString = -join ((1..$length) | ForEach-Object { Get-Random -Maximum $characters.length | ForEach-Object { $characters[$_] } })

# Output the random string
Write-Host "Random String: $randomString"

#Convert to a SecureString variable
$SecureString = ConvertTo-SecureString $randomString -AsPlainText -Force

# Output the random string
Write-Host "Secure String: $SecureString"

# Specify the drive letter
$drive = "C:"

# Turn on BitLocker for the drive
Enable-BitLocker -MountPoint $drive -RecoveryPasswordProtector -RecoveryPassword $SecureString -EncryptionMethod XtsAes128 -UsedSpaceOnly -SkipHardwareTest
```

According to the Microsoft documentation, -RecoveryPassword should generate its own value if used with -RecoveryPasswordProtector, but thats not working for me.

> -RecoveryPassword
> Specifies a recovery password. If you do not specify this parameter, but you do include the RecoveryPasswordProtector parameter, the cmdlet creates a random password. You can enter a 48-digit password. The password specified or created acts as a protector for the volume encryption key.

[Link to Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/bitlocker/enable-bitlocker?view=windowsserver2019-ps#-recoverypassword)

Also, due to existing group policy settings (which I have no control over) I have to use -RecoveryPasswordProtector, as opposed to any of the other options.

When I run the script, I get the following error:

```
PS C:\Temp> & '.\Enable Bitlocker.ps1'
Random String: 965827285728398492106062495600759349012636829500
Secure String: System.Security.SecureString
Add-RecoveryPasswordProtectorInternal : The format of the recovery password provided is invalid. BitLocker recovery
passwords are 48 digits. Verify that the recovery password is in the correct format and then try again. (Exception
from HRESULT: 0x80310035)
At C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\BitLocker\BitLocker.psm1:3675 char:36
+ ...  $nResult = Add-RecoveryPasswordProtectorInternal $MountPoint[$i] $Re ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,Add-RecoveryPasswordProtectorInternal

Enable-BitLockerInternal : Group Policy settings require that a recovery password be specified before encrypting the
drive. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8031002C)
At C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\BitLocker\BitLocker.psm1:3738 char:48
+ ... eInternal = Enable-BitLockerInternal -MountPoint $BitLockerVolumeInte ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException,Enable-BitLockerInternal
```

I have tried various different methods of inputting the -RecoveryPassword string.

1. As in the code above, having a 48 character numerical string generated, then converted to a secure string and added as a variable.
2. skipping the random string and just inputting a 48 character numerical string into the convert to secure string section.
3. Skipping the convert to secure string and just using the random string
4. Not using the random string or convert to secure string and just inputting the 48 character numerical string directly as the value for -RecoveryPassword
5. Trying to put [square brackets] around the -RecoveryPassword parameter, as it shows in the example from the Microsoft Documentation:

```
Enable-BitLocker
      [-MountPoint] <String[]>
      -RecoveryPasswordProtector
      [[-RecoveryPassword] <String>][-EncryptionMethod <BitLockerVolumeEncryptionMethodOnEnable>]
      [-HardwareEncryption][-SkipHardwareTest]
      [-UsedSpaceOnly]
      [-WhatIf]
      [-Confirm]
      [<CommonParameters>]
```

Comment: This question suggests the recovery password isn’t simply 48 random digits - it’s a smaller number of initial random bytes that are then re-coded into 48 ascii digits to give an level of error-detection when the user enters it - https://superuser.com/questions/1390599/the-format-of-the-recovery-password-provided-is-invalid-0x80310035. The *working* example in the question is also separated into blocks of 6 digits separated by ```-```. I haven’t tested this myself, but might be worth a go. Try using the “working” string from the question to test the format, then you know what you’re aiming for…

Comment: If the comment above *is* the problem, this might solve it… ```$password = 1..8 | foreach-object { get-random -maximum (256 * 256) | foreach-object { ($_ * 11).ToString("D6") } } | join-string -separator "-"```

Answer (score 0):

[`-RecoveryPassword`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/bitlocker/enable-bitlocker?view=windowsserver2019-ps#-recoverypassword) expects a `String`, but you are passing a `SecureString`.

If you are generating a random password anyway, why don't you let it generate by the cmdlet itself? Just specify the `-RecoveryPasswordProtector` parameter and *omit* the `-RecoveryPassword` parameter.